# How can i get a smooth rendered surface (without weird vertex lines)

Tags: modeling, mesh

The problem is, i want to render a smooth surface smootly, i use shade smooth but somehow it looks weird, i just want to have a polished curved and smooth sureface without that weird shading caused by smooth shading,shading flat isn't the option since the object is a cylinder

[image: side view]

here you can see the lines, (compare it to the image above):

[image: see side view]

topology shots

[image]

flat shading

[image]

it looks more closer like the output i want but i want to conserve the round surfaces to maintain the cilinder shape, but playing with flat hard surfaces at same time to give it a better shape since it's a torso

edit:

I've been playing with shading between faces, and i got a better output

[image]

but still having issue trying to shade smooth and flat at the same time, some surfaces like this, what i want to achieve is a polished and round surface at the same time, tried using F key, to create a whole new face, it didn't worked out for me

[image]

what i want to achieve in the picture above is something like this:

[image]

Comment: you have to show your mesh in Wireframe mode, I think you can simplify it a lot as your shape is quite simple

Comment: This is a result of your topology. Iif you put up an illustration of your model with 'Wire' and 'Draw all Edges' checked in its Display panel, we'd be able to point out what's wrong for you.

Comment: It's a torso, Moonboots, the idea is to make the front like a kind of shield, and make everything really smooth, since it happens what i told before,

Comment: I tought that, Robin!, and ok it's done, edited the post, uploaded the topology shots so you can take a look at it, thank you!

Comment: have you pressed the Smooth shader option in the T menu > Tool > Edit > Shading? + I think you can delete several useless edge loops.

Comment: Did you try with a subdivision surface modifier? you'll have to modify your topology anyway IMHO

Comment: in fact that is the shading i'm using, moonboots,  yeah, already tried with subsurf, Bithur ,but the output is totally different from what i want, (kind of mixture of hard surface with smooth rendering, the problem is if i try flat shading it will look like boxy)

Comment: if i shade it flat, it looks more closer like the output i want but i want to conserve the round surfaces to maintain the cylinder shape, but playing with flat hard surfaces at same time to give it a better shape since it's a torso, but dunno how to do it

Comment: You should watch some tutorials about modeling and topology. You may find some in our [ressources](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15376/11431) or on youtube

Comment: I'm glad you found a workaround but I'm afraid you won't get far with only this... Learning how and why is the solution if you want to do interesting things!

Answer (score 2):

Subsurf + Bevel is the way! , Kudos to Bithur for helping

[image]

Comment: Where can you find this in Blender?

Answer (score 0):

(update) Subsurf + Bevel + Retopologized voila! thanks again to Bithur for his help

[image]